# XSLT 1.0 to modify config file replace function

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write an XSLT to modify a config file. I have tried to use the replace function but that is only supported in 2.0 and i have tried to use translate but "true" trnaslated to "false" gets truncated to 'fals'. I cant just replace the whole modules section since our customers are in a distributed environment and I don't know if they have added any thing else to the section.
What I am starting with:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Desired output:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

This is what I thought would do the trick.

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.webServer/modules">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@name=runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: FYI - the reason why `translate()` didn't do what you expected is because it does not perform find/replace on words or entire string values, it is character  based.  You specify what character(s) to translate and it replaces with the character at that position in the second parameter. If no corresponding character, it removes it. i.e. `translate(., 'false', 'true')` says to replace "f" with "t", "a" with "r", "l" with "u", and "e" with "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests[.='true']">
    <xsl:attribute name="runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```